# Error saying struct has no member named 'total'

Tags: c

In my header I declare a structure t_flags

```
typedef struct      s_flags
{
    char            just;
    char            pad;
    size_t          prec;
    size_t          total;
    size_t          width;
    
}                   t_flags;
```

But later when I try to initialize it to a value of zero by doing

```
flags->total = 0;
```

I get the following error

```
reset_flags.c:9:7: error: ‘t_flags’ {aka ‘struct s_flags’} has no member named ‘total’
    9 |  flags->total = 0;
      |       ^~
```

I've tried recompiling, remaking the files, renaming total (from ret to total) and I still get this error.

EDIT:
I booted up my VM today to update this question, changing my main function to the following in order to clarify the usage and declaration of the structure.

```
    t_flags *flags;

    flags = (t_flags*)malloc(sizeof(t_flags));
    flags->total = 0;
```

Upon which the error simply disappeared.

Comment: Well... Somewhere you must have created an instance of `struct s_flags` called `flags`. Before anyone can answer, we would need to see how you did that. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How is `flags` defined?

Comment: Since you are new, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct s_flags
{
    char            just;
    char            pad;
    size_t          prec;
    size_t          total;
    size_t          width;
}t_flags;

t_flags f;

//f.pad = 'b'; ==> Assignment only allowed inside a function. Outside of funtion is allowed only while declaring and defining togather.

void assign()
{
        f.pad='b';
}

int main()
{
    assign();
    f.just='a';
    printf("%c ",f.just);

return 0;
}
```